# How to capture table in a structured format from this website using Beautiful soup and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape the table from this website "" and as it keeps getting updated hourly want to track changes as well. I tried scraping data using selenium but it was all in one column without any table. How to use pandas and Beautiful Soup to scrape the table in a structured format and track changes as well. This is the code I'm trying to figure out.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'subs noBorders evenRows'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Notice No","Subject","Segment Name","Category Name","Department","PDF"])
print(df)
```

It would be a help if you can help me getting data and how to keep track of new data whenever I run the script again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be informed that you don't need to include `params` as the desired information presented within main page. I've left it for you in case if you will scrape different `id`.

Also be informed that i skipped `PDF` as it's will shown `NAN` values since the `pdf` links is not an `hyperlink` . it's jsut a `logo` icon which stored within the server. but once you click on the `pdf` logo, then it's make a post request to the target to download the file. Based on that without a clear information from you so here's an answer for your requirements.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"
}

params = {
    'id': 0,
    'txtscripcd': '',
    'pagecont': '',
    'subject': ''
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    df = pd.read_html(r.content)[-1].iloc[:, :-1]
    print(df)


main("https://www.bseindia.com/markets/MarketInfo/NoticesCirculars.aspx")
```

Output:

[image]

```
    Notice No   Subject     Segment Name    Category Name   Department
0   20200923-2  Offer to Buy – Acquisition Window (Delisting) ...   Equity  Trading     Trading Operations
1   20200923-1  Change in Name of the Company.  Debt    Company related     Listing Operations
```

Comment: Wow!!Thanks for the knowledge and it worked charm but I also need the hyperlinks for the subject column in website.How can I fetch that?